# How to use a wacom tablet with Android

Tags: drawing, wacom

I would like to know how to use a Wacom graphics tablet with an Android smartphone or tablet. I have seen that it is possible in a YouTube video, wanted to know if there is any kind of driver or app that does this, because I I just tried to connect to my tablet (Wacom Graphire 2) on my smartphone and Moto G 1st generation (also already tested on a Moto x nothing).

I cannot take my PC to other places, and if the tablet worked on the smartphone that would be much more practical.

Comment: So, I purchased a new USB-OTG cable to test using a graphics tablet with my phone.  The new cable works and my tablet connects.  The side buttons "work" as clicks and "zoom".  The pen shows a "dot" cursor on my phone, but when I move the pen around, the dot always stays in the center.  Pressing down on the pen causes a click(in the center of the phone screen).  --- So, my first piece of advice is:  If it's USB, get a USB-OTG cable.   --- I think from there, I'll end up in a dead-end.  I couldn't find any references to anyone using my Huion Graphics Tablet with Android.

Comment: Locate the YouTube video and comment/ask the uploader. Best bet, since you've already seen it. But please do a follow-up if you receive any info, that way others can try also.